# CSS3: How to align text vertically within a div?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a div with a custom font and I'm trying to make it so the text has the same height as the div it's inside of.

I've been trying to find a way to override the vertical alignment of text without a div with no success.
I was hoping there was something like the text-indent method for this purpose.

[Here's a simple JsFiddle with my example.](http://jsfiddle.net/h6u7uq6g/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
.texto {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 24px;
    font-family: 'Lekton', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="texto">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `line-height` CSS property :

```
line-height : 24px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a **line-height** with a **property value** that measures the height of the containing **DIV**

```html
<style>
    .texto {
        background-color: #000;
        height: 24px;
        font-family: 'Lekton', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 24px; /* This line solves your problem */
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="texto">Test</div>
</body>
```